# RTSP Streaming with Gstreamer and OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I know there's lots of similar questions out there, however, I couldn't find any working solution to my problem. So I've been trying to run a Gstreamer pipeline inside OpenCV's VideoCapture() object. I've tried:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v4l2src ! xvimagesink')
```

but that results in  get an *Assertion Failed error*.

I will actually use rtsp stream from IP camera but for simplicity, I gave the basic USB webcam pipeline as example. My `cv2.getBuildInformation()` output states **YES** for Gstreamer.

I am working on Nvidia Jetson Nano with Python3 and OpenCV 4.1 installed afterwards. It would be great if I could achieve this so I can carry on with processing the stream etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v4l2src ! videoconvert ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Comment: Usually, we don't do follow up since users are free to create new questions on Stackoverflow. But its important to check if the behavior you get using this pipeline on the cmd-line with **gst-launch-1.0** is the same or different than what you get with `VideoCapture`.